# Correct way to join MYSQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to advance my knowledge of mysql from "I can make it work" to "I can make it work correctly". I'm working with joins right now and I was wondering the best way of doing the following:

I have 2 tables "items" and "categories". Inside the "items" table I have a field called category which will be linked to the "categories" table primary key cid. What is the best way of doing this? This is how I've always done it but I feel it's not the best way by any means

```
SELECT C.something, C.soemthing 2 FROM categories C, items I WHERE C.cid=I.category AND C.categoryName='New'
```

Comment: It's working just fine in my code and I've been using that way of joining tables for years now. What do you mean it doesn't work? I know it's not the best way it's just how I learned it when I first started programming so it's a bad habit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is already correct but I'll recommend to use `ANSI SQL-92` format

```
SELECT C.something, C.soemthing2 
FROM   categories C INNER JOIN items I 
              on C.cid=I.category
WHERE  C.categoryName='New'
```

question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to write the most optimized query. I feel like the way I'm writing it is too generic to be the "best way" of doing it

Comment: no, you are doing just fine. but you are using the old syntax of join.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would return the correct result set, however the following is more readable:

```
SELECT C.something, C.soemthing 2 
FROM categories C 
INNER JOIN items I ON C.cid = I.category 
WHERE  C.categoryName='New';
```

Comment: Your query is fine, but -1 for the misleading explanation. The older join syntax will lead to the same query plan, so it is not *inefficient*, it's simply more error-prone and less readable.

Comment: I was under the impression that the entire cartesian product was returned and THEN filtered using OP's method. Thanks for the tutorial, I have edit my post to reflect this.